Making lines not overlap
I am creating a DGE plot for 2 samples. I want the lines in the resulting plot to NOT BE STACKED on top of each other, bot to be next to each other (so that both are visible).


## Load packages
if (! require(ggplot2)) {
  install.packages("ggplot2")
}
if (! require(dplyr)) {
  install.packages("dplyr")
}
if (! require(tidyr)) {
  install.packages("tidyr")
}
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

gene_order <- c(
  "ADGRA1", "ADGRA2", "ADGRA3",
  "ADGRB1", "ADGRB2", "ADGRB3",
  "CELSR1", "CELSR2", "CELSR3",
  "ADGRD1", "ADGRD2",
  "ADGRE1", "ADGRE2", "ADGRE3", "ADGRE5",
  "ADGRF1", "ADGRF2", "ADGRF3", "ADGRF4", "ADGRF5",
  "ADGRG1", "ADGRG2", "ADGRG3", "ADGRG4", "ADGRG5", "ADGRG6", "ADGRG7",
  "ADGRL1", "ADGRL2", "ADGRL3", "ADGRL4",
  "ADGRV1"
)
gene_order <- rev(gene_order)

## Change variables
file_path <- "/home/pospim/Desktop/Work/bioinformatics/datasets/GSE189727_HIV_done/GSE189727_HIV_dataset1_SZ_DC_Axl_together - analyzed/DGE_radar"
file_name <- paste(file_path,"GPCRS-DE_analysis_DC_CDC2.tsv", sep="/")
plot_name <- paste(file_path,"DGE_plot.png", sep="/")
sample_1 <- "DC"
sample_2 <- "CDC2"

data <- read.table(file_name, header = T, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
head(data)

data[] <- lapply(data, function(x) gsub(",",".",x))
head(data)

## Clean data
data$log2FoldChange_1 <- as.numeric(as.character(data$log2FoldChange_1))
data$pvalue_1 <- as.numeric(as.character(data$pvalue_1))
data$log2FoldChange_2 <- as.numeric(as.character(data$log2FoldChange_2))
data$pvalue_2 <- as.numeric(as.character(data$pvalue_2))

## Handle NAs
data$log2FoldChange_1[is.na(data$log2FoldChange_1)] <- 0
data$pvalue_1[is.na(data$pvalue_1)] <- 1
data$log2FoldChange_2[is.na(data$log2FoldChange_2)] <- 0
data$pvalue_2[is.na(data$pvalue_2)] <- 1

## Add log10 pvalue
data$log10_pvalue_1 <- -log10(data$pvalue_1)
data$log10_pvalue_2 <- -log10(data$pvalue_2)

data$gene_symbol <- factor(data$gene_symbol, levels = gene_order)
head(data)

## Convert data to long format for plotting
data_lng <- data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("log2FoldChange"), names_to = "sample", values_to = "log2FoldChange") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("log10_pvalue"), names_to = "sample_pvalue", values_to = "log10_pvalue") %>%
  mutate(sample = case_when(
    grepl("1", sample) ~ sample_1,
    grepl("2", sample) ~ sample_2
  )) %>%
  filter((sample == sample_1 & sample_pvalue == "log10_pvalue_1") | 
         (sample == sample_2 & sample_pvalue == "log10_pvalue_2")) %>%
  select(gene_symbol, sample, log2FoldChange, log10_pvalue)
head(data_lng)

data_lng$gene_symbol <- factor(data_lng$gene_symbol, levels = gene_order)

## Plot DGE
p <- ggplot(data_lng, aes(x = log2FoldChange, y = gene_symbol, color = sample)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=0,yend=gene_symbol),
               linewidth=3, show.legend=TRUE) +
  scale_color_manual(name="Sample", values=setNames(c("blue","cadetblue1"), c(sample_1,sample_2))) +
  labs(title="Differential Gene Expression",
       x = "relative expression (log2FoldChange)", y = "") +
  theme_minimal() 

ggsave(plot_name, plot=p)
print(p)
 

structure(list(gene_symbol = structure(32:1, levels = c("ADGRV1", 
"ADGRL4", "ADGRL3", "ADGRL2", "ADGRL1", "ADGRG7", "ADGRG6", "ADGRG5", 
"ADGRG4", "ADGRG3", "ADGRG2", "ADGRG1", "ADGRF5", "ADGRF4", "ADGRF3", 
"ADGRF2", "ADGRF1", "ADGRE5", "ADGRE3", "ADGRE2", "ADGRE1", "ADGRD2", 
"ADGRD1", "CELSR3", "CELSR2", "CELSR1", "ADGRB3", "ADGRB2", "ADGRB1", 
"ADGRA3", "ADGRA2", "ADGRA1"), class = "factor"), baseMean = c("0", 
"0.660578564", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0.178397561", "1.522702077", 
"1.340522526", "0.840975621", "0.301928182", "0.150964091", "10.13217716", 
"1.313089055", "40.93692353", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0.963088173", "0.644225417", "0", "0.838976126", "0", 
"1.410153", "0", "0"), log2FoldChange_1 = c(0, 0.050537239, 0, 
0, 0, 0, -0.971180299, 0.315840199, -0.758324082, 0.551442227, 
1.736471275, 0.952373053, -0.492148172, -0.026726608, -0.21961465, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.143565116, -0.081269533, 0, -0.575736451, 
0, 3.93190614, 0, 0), lfcSE = c(NA, "2.658534114", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "4.080472857", "1.61107253", "1.693790467", "2.186266996", 
"4.048576265", "4.080472857", "0.845207802", "1.689808395", "0.404274885", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "2.887456086", "2.666317145", 
NA, "2.186422311", NA, "2.479435904", NA, NA), stat = c(NA, "0.019009438", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "-0.238006803", "0.196043439", "-0.447708319", 
"0.252230047", "0.428909118", "0.233397718", "-0.582280678", 
"-0.015816354", "-0.543231", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "0.742371504", "-0.03048007", NA, "-0.263323535", NA, "1.585806729", 
NA, NA), pvalue_1 = c(1, 0.984833577, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.811875818, 
0.844576166, 0.654363717, 0.800863255, 0.667989364, 0.815452585, 
0.560377638, 0.987380901, 0.586970765, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0.45786228, 0.975684188, 1, 0.792301222, 1, 0.112783159, 1, 
1), padj = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"0.999957765", NA, "0.999957765", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), log2FoldChange_2 = c(0, 
0.742371504, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.971180299, -0.575736451, -0.758324082, 
0.551442227, 1.736471275, 0.952373053, -0.492148172, -0.026726608, 
-0.21961465, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.050537239, -0.081269533, 
0, -0.575736451, 0, 2.887456086, 0, 0), pvalue_2 = c(1, 0.984833577, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0.811875818, 0.844576166, 0.654363717, 0.800863255, 
0.667989364, 0.815452585, 0.560377638, 0.987380901, 0.586970765, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.45786228, 0.975684188, 1, 0.792301222, 
1, 0.112783159, 1, 1), log10_pvalue_1 = c(0, 0.00663715295120108, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0905103940122029, 0.0733611785596228, 0.184180789323803, 
0.0964416320665321, 0.175230452483861, 0.0886012862135488, 0.251519203662807, 
0.00551527763353332, 0.231383528931875, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.33926513341622, 0.0106907331570114, 0, 0.101109674241976, 
0, 0.947755745205597, 0, 0), log10_pvalue_2 = c(0, 0.00663715295120108, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0905103940122029, 0.0733611785596228, 0.184180789323803, 
0.0964416320665321, 0.175230452483861, 0.0886012862135488, 0.251519203662807, 
0.00551527763353332, 0.231383528931875, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.33926513341622, 0.0106907331570114, 0, 0.101109674241976, 
0, 0.947755745205597, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = "data.frame")

Showing 1 to 19 of 32 entries, 11 total columns

I tried jitter and offset as GPT suggested, but it did not work.

Just realized the values in example data are the same for both samples, but it doesn't matter, the point is to make the lines next to each other, not on top

please share your example data by pasting the output of dput(your_data)

Thanks for adding the dput() output, that's a good start. Can you please start a new session and confirm if that data works with your code as provided? (It doesn't for me.)

Which of the plots is the desired one?

It does work for me using dput() as input

One option to achieve your desired result easily would be to use a geom_col with position="dodge" instead of a geom_segment. Additionally this requires to map on fill instead of color:
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data_lng, aes(x = log2FoldChange, y = gene_symbol, fill = sample)) +
  geom_col(
    position = "dodge"
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    name = "Sample",
    values = setNames(
      c("blue", "cadetblue1"),
      c(sample_1, sample_2)
    )
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Differential Gene Expression",
    x = "relative expression (log2FoldChange)", y = ""
  ) +
  theme_minimal()



Thank you so much Sir, gonna look into it.
